# How to press a button with the enter key

Tags: delphi

I have simple question. How do you press a button with your enter key?

I have a login screen, where I can just login with a button. But I also want to login when pressing the enter button.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Jasper

Comment: You should also know that the `Cancel` property will make the button respond to the Escape key. In a dialog box with one OK button and one Cancel button, you most often set the OK button to `Default := true` and the Cancel button to `Cancel := true`. In addition, the modal results should be `ModalResult := mrOK` and `ModalResult := mrCancel`, respectively.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the button's Default property to `True` from Object Inspector.

Comment: Where can I do that? Cause I have no idea?

Comment: You select the button you want activated with the Enter key (probably an `Ok` or `LogIn` button), you go to your Object Inspector, find the `Default` property and select `True`.